# Why string returned from a class instance keeps NoneType type even though IDLE says it is a string?

Tags: python, string, instance, nonetype

I am using a class instance which returns a string.

I am calling twice this instance and collecting returned values into a list. Then am trying to use .sort() to sort these two strings. However, when I do so it throws an error saying that the type is (Nonetype - considers it as object).

I did check with type(element of a list) and it returned type "string". I have no clue what's going on. Basically in idle it says that I have strings in a list.. but when running it throws an error saying that the NoneType (list of these strings) is not iterable.

here is an example:

```
list_of_strings = [class_method(args), class_method(another_args)] ## this instance returns string

print type(list_of_strings[0])  #prints type 'str'
```

ERROR:

```
list_sorted = list(list_of_strings.sort())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Thanks a lot!

George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable):

> `7.` The `sort()` and `reverse()` methods modify the list in place for economy
>   of space when sorting or reversing a large list. To remind you that
>   they operate by side effect, they don’t return the sorted or reversed
>   list.

Use `sorted()`:

```
list_sorted = list(sorted(list_of_strings))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sorted()`:

```
list_sorted = list(sorted(list_of_strings))
```

You are now calling `list()` on `None` which is the result of the `.sort()` call.